# How to load a xib file in a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, xib

I have been searching everywhere and nothing so far has worked for me.

Basically I want to have a .xib file called rootView.xib and inside it I want to have a UIView  (lets call it containerView) that takes up only half of the screen (so there would be the regular view and a new view). Then I want a different .xib file called firstView.xib and load it inside of containerView. So I can have a bunch of stuff on firstView.xib and a bunch of different stuff in rootView.xib and load my firstView.xib inside of containerView in rootView.xib but since it only takes up half of the screen you would still see the stuff on rootView.xib

Comment: Note, this questin is archaic.  For many years now, simply use container views [tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23399061/objective-c-how-to-add-a-subview-that-has-its-own-uiviewcontroller/23403979#23403979)

Answer (score 186, accepted):

To get an object from a xib file programatically you can use: `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyXibName" owner:self options:nil]` which returns an array of the top level objects in the xib.

So, you *could* do something like this:

```
UIView *rootView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyRootView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
UIView *containerView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyContainerView" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
[rootView addSubview:containerView];
[self.view addSubview:rootView];
```

Comment: @PaulSolt sir i have a query related to this queston. i want to open subview of xib as slide menu. When i click on menu button from the view controller  only subview(which is half screen of xib) should be slide. please help if it possible.

Comment: It not works with  `thisView.alpha = 0` , `thisView.superview`(shows nil)

Answer (score 23):

I created a sample project on github to load a UIView from a .xib file inside another .xib file. Or you can do it programmatically.

This is good for little widgets you want to reuse on different UIViewController objects.

1. New Approach: https://github.com/PaulSolt/CustomUIView
2. Original Approach: https://github.com/PaulSolt/CompositeXib

[image: Load a Custom UIView from .xib file]

Comment: Great lib, works great ! Are you still using it yourself ? :)

Comment: I use this loading technique with a Storyboard and XIB file for a custom view in my http://BrewCoffeeApp.com when the coffee recipe has started.

Answer (score 21):

You could try:

```
UIView *firstViewUIView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"firstView" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
[self.view.containerView addSubview:firstViewUIView];
```

Comment: It's not precisely what you suggested. He said his "rootView.xib" would have a subView half the size of the screen named "containerView". And into containerView he wanted to load the contents of his nib "firstView.xib".

Answer (score 21):

[Swift Implementation]

Universal way of loading view from xib:

Example:

```
let myView = Bundle.loadView(fromNib: "MyView", withType: MyView.self)
```

Implementation:

```
extension Bundle {

    static func loadView<T>(fromNib name: String, withType type: T.Type) -> T {
        if let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(name, owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as? T {
            return view
        }

        fatalError("Could not load view with type " + String(describing: type))
    }
}
```

Comment: As per latest Swift:
`let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(name, owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as? T`

Answer (score 6):

**Create a XIB file :**

> File -> new File ->ios->cocoa touch class -> next

[image]

make sure check mark "also create XIB file"

I would like to perform with `tableview` so I choosed subclass `UITableViewCell`

you can choose as your requerment

[image]

XIB file desing as your wish (RestaurantTableViewCell.xib)

[image]

we need to grab the  row height to set table each row hegiht

[image]

Now! need to huck them swift file . i am hucked  the `restaurantPhoto` and `restaurantName` you can huck all of you .

[image]

**Now adding a UITableView**

[image]

**name**
The name of the nib file, which need not include the .nib extension.

**owner**
The object to assign as the nib’s File's Owner object.

**options** 
A dictionary containing the options to use when opening the nib file.

**first**
if you do not define first then grabing all view .. so you need to grab one view inside that  set `frist` .

```
Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("yourUIView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! yourUIView
```

here is table view controller Full code

```
import UIKit

class RestaurantTableViewController: UIViewController ,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let restaurantTableviewCell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("RestaurantTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! RestaurantTableViewCell

        restaurantTableviewCell.restaurantPhoto.image = UIImage(named: "image1")
        restaurantTableviewCell.restaurantName.text = "KFC Chicken"

        return restaurantTableviewCell
    }
   // set row height
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 150
    }

}
```

you done :)

[image]

Comment: could you tell please . why down voted  then i will be glad

Comment: Your example is ok for view from xib loading. But for tableView it's wrong - reusable cells is correct way

Answer (score 5):

For **Swift 4.2**

Let's assume you have a class named **NibView** and associated nib file is **NibView.xib**

```
class NibView: UIView {

    class func getScreen() -> NibView {
        let xib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(String(describing :self), owner: self, options: nil)
        let me = xib![0] as! NibView
        return me
    }

}
```

create an instance of the class and add in your view with your specific layout whatever you want

```
let myView = NibView.getScreen()
self.yourView.addSubview(myView)
```

Answer (score 4):

**For swift 3 & 4**

```
let customView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as? CustomView
```