# IOS8 how to move an active popover

Tags: objective-c, screen-orientation, uipopover

I have developed an app for iOS7 and now trying to update it for iOS8.
Issue i have is the following:

The app screen orientation can be rotated and a few buttons in some cases move drastically. I have a few popovers that point to these buttons, so if a popover is open when screen rotates, button moves, i need the popover to also.

In iOS7 i did this by the following:
When screen rotated i updated the constraints

```
- (void) updateViewConstraints 
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation))
    {
        self.Button.constant = (CGFloat)10;
    }
    else
    {
        self.Button.constant = (CGFloat)5;
    }
    [super updateViewConstraints];
}
```

I also move the popover

```
- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{

    if(TempDisplayPopoverController == examplePopoverController)
    {
        [examplePopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[self ExamplePopoverPosition] inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
}
```

I initially load the popover

```
- (void) LoadPopover{
    examplePopover = [[examplep alloc] initWithNibName:@"exampleP" bundle:nil];
    [examplePopover setDelegate:self];
    examplePopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController: examplePopover];
    [examplePopoverController setDelegate:self];

    examplePopoverController.popoverContentSize = examplePopover.view.frame.size;

    TempDisplayPopoverController = examplePopoverController;


    if ([examplePopoverController isPopoverVisible])
    {
        [examplePopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [examplePopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[self ExamplePopoverPosition] inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
}
```

`[self ExamplePopoverPosition]` just returns button position.

This all worked fine, i was happy, iPad was happy and all behaved.

Now due to iOS8 i have to change a few bits.

`self.interfaceOrientation` is depreciated

`[examplePopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[self ExamplePopoverPosition] inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];`

in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` throws an error

`"Application tried to represent an active popover presentation: <UIPopoverPresentationController: 0x7bf59280>"`

I've managed to rectify `self.interfaceOrientation` by

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [self SetUpScreen:toInterfaceOrientation];
}

- (void) SetUpScreen:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
        toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        self.Button.constant = (CGFloat)10;
    }
    else
    {
        self.Button.constant = (CGFloat)5;
    }
    [super updateViewConstraints];
}
```

but have no idea how to resolve the popover issue. I have tried

```
popoverController: willRepositionPopoverToRect: inView:
```

but just can't to seem to get it to work.

Can anyone advice

Thanks

Comment: same problem here. We must ask Apple...

Comment: hi there, i still haven't solved this< (granted been bit distracted with something else though)

Comment: no nothing yet thats stable unfortunately

Comment: access the contents of your xib file as a UIView, and update the frame in updateViewConstraints http://stackoverflow.com/a/7814977/1546710

Answer (score 4):

In iOS 8 you can use [-viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIContentContainer_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIContentContainer/viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:) to handle screen size (and orientation) changes:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size
       withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator 
{
    [_popover dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
         // Update your layout for the new size, if necessary.  
         // Compare size.width and size.height to see if you're in landscape or portrait.
    } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        [_popover presentPopoverFromRect:[self popoverFrame] 
                                  inView:self.view
                permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                                animated:NO];
    }];
}
```

When you implement this method, the deprecated rotation methods like `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:` will not be called when running on iOS 8.

Answer (score 1):

When using `popoverController:willRepositionPopoverToRect:inView:`, when reassigning to the `rect` parameter, try using:

```
*rect = myNewRect;
```

and not:

```
rect = &presentingRect;
```

Also, make sure you have properly assigned the popover controller's delegate.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to dismiss and present the popover on rotation. UIPopoverPresentationController does that for you. You don't even need to update sourceView/sourceRect once they are set on creating the popover.

Now, the trick with `animate(alongsideTransition: ((UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void)?, completion: ((UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void)? = nil)` is that you should update your constraints in `alongsideTransition` closure, not in `completion`. This way you ensure that UIPopoverPresentationController has the updated sourceRect when restoring the popover at the end of rotation.

What might seem counter-intuitive is that inside `alongsideTransition` closure you already have your new layout that you derive your constraints calculation from.

Here's an example in Swift:

> ```
> override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
>     super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
>     coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
>         if self.popover != nil {
>             // optionally scroll to popover source rect, if inside scroll view
>             let rect = ...
>             self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(rect, animated: false)
>
>             // update source rect constraints
>             myConstraint.constant = ...
>             myConstrainedView.setNeedsLayout()
>             myConstrainedView.layoutIfNeeded()
>         }
>     }, completion: nil)
> }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Very interesting - I got this to work without updating the position manually. I don't know why this works though.

```
let buttonContainer = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44))
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44))
buttonContainer.addSubview(button)
view.addSubview(buttonContainer)

popover!.presentPopoverFromRect(button, inView: button.superview!, permittedArrowDirections: .Any, animated: true)
```

Put the button that the popover is presenting from inside a "container view". Then the popover will *automatically* adjust location upon orientation change.

Comment: Please try this solution out before down voting. I know this sounds crazy, but it works for me.