# How to create a custom button design with labels inside it in Xcode 6 using Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I am learning Swift by creating a small quiz app. I need to create a button with few labels (as shown) for the level. Please guide on how to create such type of button.
 [image: Custom button example]

The Level number and progress value is dynamic i.e. will be provided programmatically. Is there a way by which I can create a custom button assign it to a class with outlets for labels, so that I can create an object of the class and assign the values of the label and the entire class behaving as a button i.e. when clicked will move to another view controller showing the questions of that level.

Answer (score 1):

You basically answered your own question.

Create a subclass of UIView like so (showing only header file):

```
@interface MyButton : UIView

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *levelLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *progressLabel;

@end
```

Now create a layout file (.xib) with one uiview and uilabels as its children. Set the uiviews class to `MyButton` and hook up the outlets to the two labels. Remember to set the `userInteractionEnabled` property of the view to YES.

Use your custom class anywhere in your app by importing "MyButton.h".

**EDIT:**

In Swift:

```
class MyButton: UIView {

   @IBOutlet weak var lebelLabel: UILabel?
   @IBOutlet weak var progressLabel: UILabel?

   ...
}
```

Regarding comment:

> I created the xib along with labels and their outlets. Can you please tell how to use and initialise MyButton anywhere.

This has been answered on SO [countless](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=load%20xib%20uiview) times before. For one way of doing it, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814928/how-to-load-a-xib-file-in-a-uiview)

Comment: The creating of xib file option is disabled on specifying subclass of UIView.

Comment: File > New > File ... > User Interface > View. Now make this views class MyButton (Do this in Identity Inspector)

Comment: Just create the xib separately, then set the class of the view to MyButton, just like you do in Storyboards when setting the ViewController Class.

Comment: I created the xib along with labels and their outlets. Can you please tell how to use and initialise `MyButton` anywhere.

Comment: Getting a SIGABRT error on `nib.instantiateWithOwner` function. Refer to my question [Getting SIGABRT in custom uiview using xib in Xcode 6 using Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354844/getting-sigabrt-in-custom-uiview-using-xib-in-xcode-6-using-swift)